# How to solve Missing Libary errors using NDK for Facial Detection and Recognition

Tags: opencv, android-ndk

I am using the opencv jars for Facial detection and recognition and I don't have any cmake files in that package.

My app works fine below android Nougat, but a problem occurs in android Nougat and above where the alert error box says:

```
libopencv_core.so  DT_NEEDED ENTRY libtbb.so
libopencv_imageproc.so DT_NEEDED Entry libopencv_core.so
libopencv_highgui.so DT_NEEDED Entry libopencvcore.so
.........
etc
```

There are 4 libraries that have an entry missing, but they are there in the lib directory of the libsJni folder,

I went through the github thread regarding the solutions of this question, but they are all related to cmake file, and I didn't use any cmake file.

Also, I cannot set a property target for an external build.

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27261288/cmake-linking-shared-c-object-from-externalproject-produces-binaries-with-rel) but it has not helped me.

Comment: What's `libsJni`? Where are they in the APK? They need to be in `lib/$ABI_NAME`

Comment: libsJni are the libs folder which keeps the opencv.so  files , compiled at run time , useful for face recognition, after a lot of research it says (as per android docs of android os >=23)   the resoluton given by them is 
: make sure all required libraries are referenced by SONAME only. It is better to let the runtime linker to find and load those libraries as the location may change from device to device.               And i still confuesd how to referenced by soname to jnilibs opencv.so files    ...................kindly guide any one.....here...